# Issues with using Active class in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently, the ‘Active’ class is seen on the FAQ and it creates a misleading impression [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/js8TZ.png). As of now, the **hovering** still exists in White. I want to achieve where *An active element will be in White and display accordingly when the user clicks* [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUybU.png). I have provided my .html and .css, however, the provided snippet output is inaccurate. Please use your preferred software such as Visual Studio, etc. Thank you.

```css
/*
    DEMO STYLE
*/

@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

i,
span {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header h3,
#sidebar.active .CTAs {
    display: none;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header strong {
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    text-align: left;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a i {
    margin-right: 0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#sidebar.active ul ul a {
    padding: 10px !important;
}

#sidebar.active .dropdown-toggle::after {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
    display: none;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #7386D5;
    background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li a i {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        min-width: 80px;
        max-width: 80px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: -80px !important;
    }
    .dropdown-toggle::after {
        top: auto;
        bottom: 10px;
        right: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
        transform: translateX(50%);
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }
    #sidebar .sidebar-header h3,
    #sidebar .CTAs {
        display: none;
    }
    #sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
        display: block;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a {
        padding: 20px 10px;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a span {
        font-size: 0.85em;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a i {
        margin-right: 0;
        display: block;
    }
    #sidebar ul ul a {
        padding: 10px !important;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a i {
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/mainCSS.css" />
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/js/all.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
                <strong>BS</strong>
            </div>


            <!-- -->
            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <li>
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
                        <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                        Home
                    </a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
                        About
                    </a>
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
                        <i class="fas fa-copy"></i>
                        Pages
                    </a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-image"></i>
                        Portfolio
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-question"></i>
                        FAQ
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
                        Contact
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- -->
        </nav>

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="content">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <!-- Sidebar 1 -->
                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                        <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                        <span>Minimise Sidebar</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
            $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

***Update 1***
The following result is correct https://ibb.co/phP4c8d, however how do I make it White for the remaining elements? It's something like this https://codepen.io/gearmobile/pen/bByZdG. Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe it requires a JavaScript.

Comment: what is that you are expecting. can you be more clear

Comment: I want to achieve where An active element will be in White and display accordingly when the user clicks

Comment: please create a [mcve], emphasis on minimal - don't just post all your code and expect us to sift through it - if you are only wanting to style the menu, then just post code and css for the menu

Comment: What do you mean with "display accordingly"?

Comment: If they click on FAQ, the white label will appear same goes if they click on contact the white label will display accordingly

Answer (score 0):

[image]

i dont know if i understood your question but i think what you want is this,

```
 #sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #6d7fcc;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: You almost got it but I added another question to your answer. Please refer to the updated question. Thank you!